# Unable to style specific view in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to get one of my views in Angular to display with a specific background. I'm finding that, with the code below, the entire view that I'm trying to style disappears.

All relevant code is below:

HTML (index.html):

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Angular view:

```
<div class="main-body">
  <div ng-switch="xxCtrl.xxx">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: url('../img/main-bg.jpeg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-body {
    background-color: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.6);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow: scroll; overflow-x:hidden;
    z-index: -1000000;
}
```

I have tried moving the main-body class into the ng-switch, in the ng-switch itself, etc. I even tried setting in-line CSS using ng-style, but I couldn't get the height set to 100%, regardless of how I formatted it. The only time I've been able to get the background to display as I wished was when I set the wrapper div outside of ng-view in index.html to main-body. However, I really don't want the background I'm creating to display across all views - just the one.

I have a feeling this is likely a CSS-related issue, not an Angular one. If anyone can point me in the right direction here, it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this problem by changing the height to 100vh instead of 100%.